# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $ y=0 , z=1-x^2, z=x^2-1, y+z=1 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

i need to know the first steps and strategies of solving this kind of problems

i know that i need to find the limits of x and y and then do the integral of a certain functions by dxdy

Comment: The first thing you should do is sketch this. After you sketch this you must determine the bounds for your integrands and then integrate.

Comment: @mathtastic i should sketch $y=0,y=-x^2+2, y=x^2 $ on 2d graph ?

Comment: three dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Sketching the solid, as suggested in the comments above, is the first thing you should do.

After that, a good way to get started on this particular problem is to sketch the curves

$\;\;\;z=1-x^2$ and $z=x^2-1$ in the $xz$-plane.

This region is the projection of the solid in the $xz$-plane, so you can use this to find your limits for $x$ and $z$.

Then (if you are using a double integral)
you can use the equations $y=0$ and $y+z=1$

to find the $y$-values corresponding to any point $(x,z)$ in the projection in the $xz$-plane.

The difference of these $y$-values gives the length of the solid corresponding to each point $(x,z)$,

so it is the function to be integrated.

---

This should give $\displaystyle V=\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2-1}^{1-x^2}(1-z)\;dz\;dx$

Comment: yes i am using double integral so i should find the range of x ,y and z and the function that should be integrated , range of z is [0,1] if i am correct

Comment: You can work it this way, but I believe it's easier to find the range of $x$ and $z$ and then use $y$ to find the function to be integrated.

Comment: can you explain more sir ? because we still didn't learn this material in class . i still dont know the exact strategy on how to find the range of x and z or y and how to figure out the integrated function. [ all we did in class is to learn how to solve a given double integral ]

Comment: Yes, I will edit my answer to give more explanation.

Comment: ok i drew z=1−x2 and z=x2−1 and the range of x= [-1,1] and so does z am i at the right path ?